# How can I lock an INSERT operation

Tags: sql-server, transaction

OK, I know the title is confusing, let me rephrase with a description of the problem. The environment is SQL Server 2012.

I have a table with Customers

```
Id
1
```

And a table with their transactions

```
Id, CustomerId, Amount
1, 1, 10
2, 1, 20
3, 1, -5
```

So the balance for a customer is the SUM of the amount column. In this example, customer 1 has 10+20-5=25 balance.

We have an external system where we need to transfer funds using a webservice (so a ditributed transaction is not possible). We must first make sure that the user has enough balance. So he may transfer 20 with the following insert

```
4, 1, -20
```

But if he then tried to transfer another 20, he should fail since now he only has 5 left.

The problem is when the two requests for withdrawal come at the same time at the server. So the balance check is executed with a few milliseconds difference, and returns 25 to both requests (since the insert is not executed yet because the web service has not returned in the first request)

My question is, what lock should I use, in order to ensure that the second transaction fails? I do not want to do a table lock since this table is used by thousand other users. How else can I be sure that the second transaction waits until the first is complete? Also, using code level lock would not do since we are using a webfarm and two seperate servers could be used for the two requests.

Thanks,
Themos

Comment: What isolation level are you using ?

Comment: I am using READ COMMITTED, but I can use a different one if required